# ajaxified file upload in jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload

I want to do a file upload without posting an entire form. The file upload works fine, but the whole form is submitted. This works fine when validation is correct. But when p.e. a required field is empty, the upload does not work and a error message is returned (required field missing)
So i tried to ajax the file upload (ajax=true). But then the upload does nothing.

I tried a work around bu putting the file upload and other fields in different forms. This works, but the result is that data you changed in the other fields is disregarded when doing the file upload.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code I use:

```
<t:inputFileUpload id="fileupload" value="#{prospectDetail.upFile}" size="50" />
<h:outputLabel for="description" value="#{msg.prospectdetail_description}"/>
<mw:inputText id="description" size="40" value="#{prospectDetail.fileDescription}" />
<p:commandButton styleClass="button" value="#{msg.common_upload}" action="#{prospectDetail.upload}" ajax="false" process="@form" onbegin="busyPopup.show()" oncomplete="busyPopup.hide();"/>
```

Comment: had same issue with primefaces upload, but then i set it to auto upload upon file selection, and it work great, check if you have auto upload in the component you use, this should solve the submitting issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **not** possible to upload files by first version of `XMLHttpRequest` (which is the core Ajax request controller object in JavaScript). The second version of `XMLHttpRequest` supports it, but this is not implemented by `<p:commandButton>` (and has currently low browser support).

As you seem to be using PrimeFaces already, why don't you just use its own [`<p:fileUpload>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml) component? The [single upload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml) or even the [auto upload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/auto.xhtml) examples should do it for you (don't forget to remove the MyFaces extensions filter from the `web.xml` after adding the PrimeFaces' file upload filter!). The PrimeFaces' `<p:fileUpload>` will automatically utilize XHR2 file upload whenever available.

> *I tried a work around bu putting the file upload and other fields in different forms. This works, but the result is that data you changed in the other fields is disregarded when doing the file upload.*

If you put the bean in the view scope instead of the request scope and return `null` or `void` from action methods, then this should work.

Comment: <p:fileUpload> rulez :)  You now if it is possible to ad an extra field description(string) to the file and have it send to the bean on file upload event?